# text outside div in chrome (css)

Tags: html, css

http://im41.gulfup.com/a2ZT5.jpg

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 }

.table {
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

i have a problem with styling this div the text going outside the div or td

i tried to use white-space and remove line height and overflow:hidden,visible,auto but not success.

please help me

Comment: Could you making something on JSFiddle or provide a link to the actual page?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a CSS property called word-break:

```
.class{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```